# How to conditionally scale out aws asg instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, autoscaling

I have 4 aws ec2 instances which service requests.

For new code to be deployed, I launch 4 new instances (on which new code builds) and after:
**(a) these 4 new instances appear as `healthy` under `Load balancing>Target Groups>Registered Targets>Status`,**

I scale in and the older four instances are terminated.

Step 1
Scale out:

> aws autoscaling set-desired-capacity --auto-scaling-group-name
>   MY-UI-CODE --desired-capacity 8 --honor-cooldown

Step2 : check  Load balancing>Target Groups>Registered Status>Status

Step 3 : If 2 is healthy,
Scale in:

> aws autoscaling set-desired-capacity --auto-scaling-group-name
>   MY-UI-CODE --desired-capacity 4 --honor-cooldown

Currently I have both ^ commands saved to two shell scripts. 
I run first script, then wait some 10 minutes, and check status, and then run the second script.

How do I link the two so that the scale in kicks in only after verifying that (a) happens?

My final goal is to 
put Step 1 , 2 3 into a shell script and reduce manual work of checking.

Comment: I wonder if you could `describe-auto-scaling-groups` and count the number of Healthy instances? Or use `aws elbv2 describe-target-health` to count the number of healthy targets. You'd be much better-off writing the logic in a program (eg Python) rather than using the AWS CLI, since it is easier to parse the results.

Comment: I'm interested in health status of :
`Load balancing>Target Groups>Registered Targets>Status of a instances under target group XX` ; Let me give  aws elbv2 describe-target-health a shot.